# Add/Remove Components in runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a cube in script(c#). I want to remove the BoxCollider since i am developing a 2D game and exchange it through the BoxCollider2d. Then i want to add a RigiBody2D and show the cube in my world. The Problem is that i always get the error:

> Can't add component 'BoxCollider2D' to Cube because it conflicts with
>   the existing 'BoxCollider' derived component!
>   UnityEngine.GameObject:AddComponent()
>   CreateCube:OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D) (at
>   Assets/Scripts/CreateCube.cs:15)

I get this error but the Code works anyways. BUT it only goes till the line Destroy(cube.collider); and thats it! The BoxCollider is defenitly removed correctly cause when i take a look at the created objects it is gone. I really dont know why the compiler is telling me that there is a existing BoxCollider.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CreateCube : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
    {
        // Create Cube
        GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);

        // Destroy BoxCollider
        Destroy(cube.collider);

        // Add BoxCollider2D
        cube.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>();

        // Add RigiBody2D
        cube.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        // Show Cube in World
        cube.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0);
    }
}
```

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: you should probably not create a Cube primitive but a 2D sprite to begin with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Destroy` will always wait until after the current `Update` loop to remove the component, so the `Collider` is not removed when you are adding the `BoxCollider2D`. Use `DestroyImmediate` instead.

However I would recommend to create a `prefab` with the things you want and use `Instantiate` instead. Like this:

```
// Create Cube
GameObject cube = Instantiate(yourPrefab, new Vector(0, 0.5f, 0), Quaternion.identidy) as GameObject;
```

Comment: Saw now this was a 1 year old post, I have no idea why it showed up so early in the list. But my answer might help another :P