# Unity Gear VR error on build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, gear-vr

I.m trying to setup and build https://resources.samsungdevelopers.com/Gear_VR/030_Create_VR_App_or_Game_Using_a_Game_Engine/Exercise_2%3A_Create_a_Splash_Screen/Step_7%3A_Build_and_Run_the_Application

When I try and build the application it throws the following error:
Assets/Workshop/Scripts/TextureLoader.cs(114,31): error CS1105: `TextureLoader.GetFilesWithExtensions(this DirectoryInfo, params string[])': Extension methods must be declared static

```
// Gets the list of files in the directory by extention and filters for our specified ones (images)
public IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetFilesWithExtensions (this DirectoryInfo dir, params string[] extensions) {
    IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = dir.GetFiles();
    return files.Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension));
}

public bool isFinishedLoadingFirstTexture() {
    return mFinishedFirstTexture;
}
```

**I have already changed it to a public static class in the header.**

Comment: extension _methods_

Answer (score 0):

The class being static doesn't do much for the methods. You need to make your method static for the extensions to work!

```
public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetFilesWithExtensions (this DirectoryInfo dir, params string[] extensions) {
    IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = dir.GetFiles();
    return files.Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension));
}
```

I wrote an extension method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42133812/6730803) if you need another example!

Comment: what if the class if private?

Answer (score 0):

I order to make an extension method, the class must be `public` and `static`.

The function must be `public` and `static` too. You missed this part.

```
public static class TextureLoader
{
    public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetFilesWithExtensions(this DirectoryInfo dir, params string[] extensions)
    {
        IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = dir.GetFiles();
        return files.Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension));
    }
}
```

Comment: when I change it to a static class it through a whole host of errors. This was file that came with the example project.

Comment: it was originally `private IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetFilesWithExtensions (this DirectoryInfo dir, params string[] extensions) {
  IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = dir.GetFiles();
  return files.Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension));
 }`

Comment: Sorry, extension method is supposed to be public if you are calling it from class other the class it resides in. I can't help without access to the project since it looks like there are other problems in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code this way, the error will disappear

```
private IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetFilesWithExtensions(DirectoryInfo dir, string[] extensions)
{
    IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = dir.GetFiles();
    return files.Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension));
}
```